# Can't change the datadir for MariaDB mysql files

Tags: centos, mariadb

This is CentOS 8.1 and MariaDB 10.3 database server.

I have followed the directions I've seen in several places to relocate the datadir from the default of /var/lib/mysql to /home/mysql. /home is the RAID.

I've made the change in /etc/my.cnf putting this before the !include stuff, but it appears to be still pointing to /var/lib/mysql.

When I have done this, mysql complains and it won't bring let my run the mysql command.

I have looked in /etc/my.cnf.d and see the default is still there in mariadb-server.cnf.

I see this message in the log and wasn't sure if this was related or not?

```
Mar 11 11:58:44 myserver systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...

Mar 11 11:58:44 myserver mysql-prepare-db-dir[6349]: **Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.**

Mar 11 11:58:44 myserver mysql-prepare-db-dir[6349]: **If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mysql-prepare-db-dir.**
```

I have tried running mysql-prepare-db-dir, but the same messages appear in the logs.

Comment: Check the protection mechanism -- selinix?

Comment: What is the datadir in `/etc/my.cnf`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put `datadir` in a [mysqld] section, and be aware that when configs are loaded, the LAST statement wins, not the first as you seem to be implying by putting it before the !includes. Do a `grep -R` for `datadir` in your MySQL configs and check where it is being set, if anywhere.

In reality, you are going about it the wrong way, though. It is a much better practice to `mount --bind /home/mysql /var/lib/mysql`. And make sure you `restorecon -rv /var/lib/mysql` to get your SELinux labels correct.